# VBA errors not popping up when the code fails

Tags: vba, excel

I know this is probably a little backwards but in this case I want the errors.  I am working on a project and I am no longer getting pop up run time errors in VBA.  The code just stops and I have to go step by step to find it.  I must have done something to make it stop doing this but I have no idea what it was.

Any suggestions?

Best regards,  CK

Comment: Would recommend sharing your code.

Comment: I will wait for the next 30 mins for you to edit your question. Post which even I will have to vote to close this question :) In the meantime if someone else votes then too bad :D

Comment: Is your macro using some COM object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can think of Three reasons

1. Close and reopen the excel file. Ensure that before you re-open there is no left over instance of Excel in task manager.
2. You are using `On Error Resume Next`
3. Incorrect Error Handling

Comment: I was using On Error Resume Next.  Thank you!